# Sqoop eval is working but sqoop import is giving error

Tags: hdfs, sqoop, biginsights

When i run sqoop eval its give me output. But when i do sqoop import its giving following error

```
    Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:746)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

I am using BigInsight. Anyone can please tell what is the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Sqoop Import uses Map-reduce whereas Sqoop Eval doesn't. You would be executing Sqoop Eval from a node that has connectivity to the Source.

For Sqoop Import to work all the Nodes of your Cluster need to have connectivity to the Source.